# Remove parent JSON element depending on child value

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON with lots of empty content:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "category": "login",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Name",
                    "value": "",
                },
                {
                    "label": "E-Mail",
                    "value": "",
                },
                {
                    "label": "Password",
                    "value": "123456",
                },
                {
                    "label": "Website",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "label": "Name X",
                            "value": ""
                        },
                        {
                            "label": "Name Y",
                            "value": "another one"
                        },…
                    ]
                },…
            ]
        },…
    ]
}
```

The nesting goes several levels deeper. This shows only the first level. I want to delete all elements of "fields" (or whatever the array's key in deeper levels is), where their "value" is empty.

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "category": "login",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Password",
                    "value": "123456",
                },
                {
                    "label": "Website",
                    "fields": [
                        {
                            "label": "Name Y",
                            "value": "another one"
                        },…
                    ]
                },…
            ]
        },…
    ]
}
```

How can I do this in Javascript?

Comment: It's not a trivial question, so you probably want to elaborate a bit more on it. You will probably have to resort to recursion. So the behavior you want is: iterate through all the _arrays_ of **objects** that have a `value`  property, and remove the entire **object** from the _array_ if `value` is empty? Can you please include a **usable** excerpt of input data (preferrably one that **is** many levels deep) and show what your desired output is?

Comment: Edited the code accordingly to reflect "deeper".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way to iterate through the JSON object:

```
function remove(jsondata) {
  for (let i in jsondata) {
    if (jsondata[i].value != undefined && jsondata[i].value == '') {
       delete jsondata[i];
    }
    else if (typeof jsondata[i] === "object") remove(jsondata[i]);
  }
}
```

Not sure, if it's the most elegant way, but it works so far.

Comment: +1 on that. I personally think it looks clean and as elegant as it gets. It had to have recursion. If it works, be sure to select your own answer as the selected solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` method,you could get a filtered array
it returned `Boolean`. if `value`  exist,it will be true

```js
var list=JSON.parse(data)
list.items=list.items.map(val=>{
  val.fields=val.fields.filter(v=>v.value})
  return val
})
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: I don't think it solves OP's question at all. The OP specifically said _the nesting goes several levels deeper_, so you probably want to employ recursion to traverse those `n` levels. This solution goes no deeper than the first level - not to mention that while traversing one must identify whether an element is an object, array or primitive value to decide what to do with it. Not a simple task. To be fair, it's a poorly formulated question (the very reason why it has been downvoted, and not by me).

Comment: @gyohza you are right,but author doesn't give  `deeper` code

Comment: You're right. I asked the OP in the comments. Let's wait and see. :)

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for many data processing tasks. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could answer your questions

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (input) => objectScan(['**[*].value'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
    if (value === '') {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

const obj = { items: [{ category: 'login', fields: [{ label: 'Name', value: '' }, { label: 'E-Mail', value: '' }, { label: 'Password', value: '123456' }, { label: 'Website', fields: [{ label: 'Name X', value: '' }, { label: 'Name Y', value: 'another one' }] }] }] };

console.log(prune(obj)); // return count of pruned entries
// => 3
console.log(obj);
// => { items: [ { category: 'login', fields: [ { label: 'Password', value: '123456' }, { label: 'Website', fields: [ { label: 'Name Y', value: 'another one' } ] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@16.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for this.