# remove JSON parent property only if child has empty [] JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to remove any parent JSON item if the child has empty [], not if the child is empty. The nested JSON has arrays of JSON as well

Here is an example JSON:

```
{
 "hi": 596,
 "hello": {
    "a" : []
  },
 "h": {
    "a" : ""
  },
 "hey" : {
    "a" : 293,
    "b" : "23",
    "c" : {
      "1" : []
     },
    "d" : [{
      "1" : {
         "z" : []
       },
      "2" : "123"
     }]
  },
 "hola" : 123
}
```

How I would like the output to look like:

```
{
 "hi": 596,
 "h": {
    "a" : ""
  },
 "hey" : {
    "a" : 293,
    "b" : "23",
    "d" : [{
      "2" : "123"
    }]
  },
 "hola" : 123
}
```

How can I do this?

I tried regex `JSON.stringify(data).replace(/,\\n\s*\\"(.*?)\\":\s*\[\]*,/g, "")` but I believe this only matched the child node. Are there better ways to go about this?

Comment: Sorry, Duplicate of [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077026/remove-parent-json-element-depending-on-child-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077026/remove-parent-json-element-depending-on-child-value)

Comment: Your json is invalid. missing a couple of commas.

Comment: @callback should be fixed!

Comment: @takendarkk is it possible to only remove only those with empty brackets? I have edited my question to show

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove parent JSON element depending on child value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62077026/remove-parent-json-element-depending-on-child-value)

Comment: @biberman I would like to only remove cases when there is an empty array, but not all empty values (see edited question)

Comment: I think the linked question is the solution. You just have to modify it a tiny bit, e.g. ```...value != []...```

Answer (score 1):

This might require a bit of optimization, but you can use recursion to achieve your goal

```js
const input = {
  "hi": 596,
  "hello": {
    "a": []
  },
  "h": {
    "a": ""
  },
  "hey": {
    "a": 293,
    "b": "23",
    "c": {
      "1": []
    }
  },
  "hola": 123
};


function removeEmpty(obj, parent = null, finalResult = {}) {

  Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
    const objKey = obj[key];
    if (objKey.constructor === Array && objKey.length === 0) {
      return
    }
    if (typeof objKey === 'object') {
      return removeEmpty(objKey, key, finalResult);
    } else {

      if (parent) {
        if (!finalResult[parent]) {
          finalResult[parent] = {}
        }

        finalResult[parent][key] = objKey

      } else {
        finalResult[key] = objKey;
      }
    }
  });
  return finalResult;
}

const output = removeEmpty(input);

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Apologies, I just realized that some of the JSON I am using has arrays of JSON nested inside (I have updated my question). Do you know what I can add to the code to address this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague (what should happen if only some children are empty?) and hence I'd recommend using a library. That will make it easier to iterate on your solution as edge cases pop up. Here is how you could solve it using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan)

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const data = { hi: 596, hello: { a: [] }, h: { a: '' }, hey: { a: 293, b: '23', c: { 1: [] }, d: [{ 1: { z: [] }, 2: '123' }] }, hola: 123 };

const prune = objectScan(['**.*.*'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value) && value.length === 0) {
      delete gparent[gproperty];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
});

console.log(prune(data));
// => 3

console.log(data);
// => { hi: 596, h: { a: '' }, hey: { a: 293, b: '23', d: [ { '2': '123' } ] }, hola: 123 }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)